# How works simple table load with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS starting with that example: http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/

but when I tried to download in localhost, not works. I think that is a URL problem in /echo/json':

```
$scope.loadPeople = function() {
        var httpRequest = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: mockDataForThisTest

        }).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.people = data;
        });

    };
```

But I don't know how to solve it. Any idea or hint?

My finally idea is load `json` from a search petition. It's possible that 'data' will be charged from web or online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url: '/echo/json/' is a feature of JsFiddle. If you look at the tabs to the left, in Ajax Requests you can see the usage. It probably won't work with this url in localhost.

You need to create a web project, where you can send your request. You could send some search parameters from client side, then filter the data with those parameters in the server and then return the filtered data to show.

The following article will give you some good ideas

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/ajax.html

This link provides a hands on example by a really good tutor.

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/learning-angularjs-by-example-the-customer-manager-application

Comment: Thanks @adib.mosharrof! I check it but is there any easier example? I'm very newbie :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: You could try looking at the following sites for good tutorials
https://egghead.io/
scotch.io
pluralsight
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial
www.w3schools.com/angular/
search angular basic in youtube

These are just some examples, there are lots of other wonderful sites out there